# 12V LED install with adressable LEDS

Tags: led-strip

I am a software geek.  I have a (fairly big) boat.  12V is everywhere.  I want to replace all the incandescent LED courtesy lights (about 12 very small light fixtures in 2 different zones) with programmable RGBW LED lights.

I know about addressable LEDs, but these are almost exclusively 5V systems. Which is kind of the point of this question.

I would like to have each LED light fixture have about 10 addressable RGBW LEDs installed in a single fixture BUT control each fixture as if it was one big pixel.  I want the switches for the courtesy lights to perform their original on-off function.  I want an arduino controller to run code for me so that I can control the zones separately and control the color and the brightness of each courtesy light fixture in each zone.  I also want the arduino to sense the on/off state of each zone and STOP sending data to the addressible LEDs when they are supposed to be off.

I can code.  I have done many arduino projects with LEDs before. But what is baffling me is how to power and control 10 5V LEDs at potentially full power with 12V WITHOUT having to have a step down transformer/transistor at every fixture vampiring DC all the time.  Oh and did I mention the fixtures were SMALL?  Think 2.5 in puck lights.  But OVAL.

Someone HAS to have done this before.  Or maybe I am chasing a unicorn?  I am SO not an electrical engineer.

Comment: i got 12v addressable led xmas lights from amazon, they are out there, and pretty bright too, you might not need 10 of them. You have to wire them always on and then feed your switches to the control system, otherwise you can't change nuthin when the switch is off.

Comment: They make a signal amplifier (Amazon SP901E) which can be powered by 12V and splits 1-->4.  If all I run to the input is ground and data from the controller, then I believe VCC on/off should work just like the light switch did without vampiric consumption.  Then I can run a couple fixtures from each output while maintaining a single controller.  If I get 1 per zone, I just have to make sure my controller can run 2 digital outputs the distance to each amplifier without too much signal loss.  Would coax improve the runs to the amplifiers in each zone? I have a ton of TV style coax laying around

Comment: lookup how to use a pixel as a repeater to extend distance, a "sacrificial pixel".

Answer (score 1):

> I can code. I have done many arduino projects with LEDs before. But what is baffling me is how to power and control 10 5V LEDs at potentially full power with 12V WITHOUT having to have a step down transformer/transistor at every fixture vampiring DC all the time. Oh and did I mention the fixtures were SMALL? Think 2.5 in puck lights. But OVAL.

Use 12V addressable LEDs such as the ws2811 or ws2815.  Note that while the absolute maximum is 13.5V, you'll want to make sure your "12V" is reasonably well regulated or else include a DCDC converter anyway to regulate it or you may burn out the diodes.

Comment: This will work if the maximum distance between LEDs isn't more than about 2 meters. That is the rated driving distance.

Comment: @Mattman944 Yea, I have a feeling this is going to be my downfall.  They make an very small WIFI enabled ASIC that will run Arduino OS which I can use to make all the code and control be resident at each fixture, but then the courtesy lights will be dependent on the WIFI which is not optimal AND if the ASIC needs reflashed, I will have to de-install the fixture.